# Android app excruciatingly slow when debugging on device

Tags: android, eclipse

I would expect a little overhead but I'm talking 1-4 fps, as opposed to 40-60 when running normally without the debugger on the same device. Anyone know what might cause this? The device is a Motorola DroidX, ADT version is 22.0.1.

Comment: It would help if you put maybe the app that you are debugging? Is the whole phone slow or just the app?

Comment: Debugging is naturally slower plus the device you have is not exactly fast by todays standards

Comment: There are precious few situations which demand a debugger - it can be handy when it works well, but almost everything can be sorted out with skillful use of logging.